# Why is my <Div> disappearing when I add Class to my <span> within it?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to take a variable and display it on my html page via CSS for a Graphical display in OBS streaming software.
Every time I add the class .wrappers to the span id p1Name (as well as p2Name) the text disappears from the html output in OBS.
What is causing the text to disappear? As otherwise it perfectly is displayed when I don't include the class .wrappers

I've tried modifying overall page settings, the class specifications and moving the object itself but the text just seems to have disappeared.

**Edit** Changing the opacity within wrappers does not affect the visibility of the object

```js
//Time stuff
let time = document.getElementById("current-time");

setInterval(() => {
  let d = new Date();
  time.innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString(navigator.language, {
    hourCycle: 'h23',
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit'
  });
}, 1000);
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Futura";
  src: url('Resources/Fonts/Brandon_bld.otf');
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Futura";
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.graphicBox {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1800px;
  height: 105px;
  background: rgb(51, 116, 182);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(51, 116, 182, 0.75) 0%, rgba(110, 83, 180, 0.75) 70%);
  border-radius: 15px;
  bottom: 40px;
  left: 50px;
  filter: drop-shadow(-2px 2px 4px black);
}

.statusBox {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Futura";
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 8px;
  font-size: 40px;
  width: 130px;
  height: 70px;
  background: rgb(231, 231, 231);
  border-radius: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 125px;
  left: 100px;
  filter: drop-shadow(-2px 2px 4px black);
}

.timeDisplay {
  width: 140px;
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: left;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  bottom: 58px;
  left: 771px;
}

.timeZone {
  width: 60px;
  height: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: left;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  bottom: 40px;
  left: 812px;
}

.scoreboardP1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 150px;
  bottom: 60px;
  width: 300px;
}

.scoreboardP2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 450px;
  bottom: 60px;
  width: 300px;
}

.wrappers {
  position: absolute;
  width: 340px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 54px;
  top: 356px;
  opacity: 0;
  color: black;
}

#p1Wrapper {
  bottom: 540x;
  left: 300px;
  color: white;
}

#p2Wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 100px;
  color: white;
}

.scoreDisplay {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  align: center;
  font-family: "Avant";
}

#p1Format {
  top: 30px;
  left: 1160px;
}

#p2Format {
  top: 30px;
  left: 1450px;
}

.scoreBox {
  position: absolute;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  align: center;
}

#p1Box {
  top: 28px;
  left: 1150px;
}

#p2Box {
  top: 28px;
  left: 1440px;
}
```

```html
<div class="graphicBox">
</div>

<div class="statusBox">
  <p>NEXT</p>
</div>


<div class="timeDisplay">
  <h1 id="current-time"></h1>
</div>



<div class="timeZone">
  <p>EST</p>
</div>


<div id="overlayP1" class="scoreboardP1">
  <span id="p1Wrapper" class="wrappers">
            <span id="p1Name" class="names"></span>
  </span>
</div>

<div class="scoreboardP2">
  <span id="p2Wrapper">
            <span id="p2Name" class="names"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: What effect did you expect `opacity: 0;` to have?!

Comment: I tried setting it to 1 but nothing changed @Quentin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seem to be two things in the CSS class `.wrappers`.

Because `.wrappers` has the property `position: absolute`, the element was disappearing out of the screen.
Also, with the propriety `opacity: 0` the item is invisible.

So, by commenting out these elements in the CSS:

```
  .wrappers {
    /* position: absolute; */
    width: 340px;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 54px;
    top: 356px;
    /* opacity: 0; */
    color: black;
  }
```

I can now see both `p1Name` and `p2Name` when the parent span `p1Wrapper` and `p2Wrapper` have the `wrappers` class added to them, like this:

```
<span id="p1Wrapper" class="wrappers">
```

Also, just some quick notes:

- `align: center` is not a valid CSS property.
- While testing I added inside the `p1Name` span some words "*testp2*" so I could see the changes after formatting: `<span id="p2Name" class="names">testp2</span>`

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to figure out if it was out of bounds or not, but I guess the transparency didn't help with that.
In the javascript code, its supposed to shift from 0 to 1 to fade in with animation. But I figured it wasn't affecting since I couldn't see anything at all even when it was set to 1 (but off screen)